# Deploy failed to android device when I add MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS permission in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

When I start a new Xamarin Forms solution (Android, Ios) on Visual Studio 2022 and add `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission to the manifest and try to deploy the app to my Google Pixel 6 device - I see this:

```
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

And there are no any error in the output or error list.

- Device: `Google Pixel 6`
- Target Android version in manifest: `API Level 31 - S`

Can I somewhere find a reason of this?

Comment: I did a test, but I cann't reproduce this problem on my side. You can try to remove the bin folders and obj folders and rebuild your app, then try again.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT, I have tried that - nothing changed

Comment: You can also check if you have installed the app in your device.If yes, then uninstall it and install it again.  If it still doesn't work, try restarting your VS.